# Windows 7 intermittently fails to open samba shares with 0x80070043 - the network name cannot be found

Tags: 14.04, samba

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 box called watson with a static IP 192.168.7.101 running:

- dnsmasq
- samba

I also have a bunch of windows 7 home premium boxes that get their IP addresses from dnsmasq over DHCP. Watson shares two directories with no authentication (I trust anyone on my LAN, and it's all snapshotted on crashplan). However while the windows boxes can see the shares fine, attempting to open them often fails with `0x80070043` - the network name cannot be found. Restarting smbd and nmbd often makes the problem go away for a bit. Sometimes I can open one share, but not the other.

This has worked fine for years, but started going wrong after upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04 and/or moving house with new routers that enabled ipv6 and/or whatever security updates have been pushed by Ubuntu/Microsoft since mid-December

Things I have tried:

- Disabling ipv6 everywhere
- Enabling WINS server on samba
- Disabling CUPS support in SAMBA
- Enabling the various netbios DHCP options in dnsmasq

Any advice strongly appreciated. At this rate, I'm going to have to move to FreeNAS.

My personal tech level is a long-term C++ programmer (with a slowly degrading CCNA), so feel free to suggest techy solutions.

My samba config looks like this:

```
[global]
    server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
    server role = standalone server
    map to guest = Bad Password
    obey pam restrictions = Yes
    pam password change = Yes
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    unix password sync = Yes
    syslog = 0
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    max log size = 1000
    name resolve order = wins, hosts, bcast
    load printers = No
    printcap name = /dev/null
    disable spoolss = Yes
    wins support = Yes
    usershare allow guests = Yes
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    idmap config * : backend = tdb
    printing = bsd
    print command = lpr -r -P'%p' %s
    lpq command = lpq -P'%p'
    lprm command = lprm -P'%p' %j

[music]
    path = /raid/music
    read only = No
    guest ok = Yes

[data]
    path = /raid/data
    read only = No
    guest ok = Yes


My Dnsmasq (stripped of comments) looks like this:

This has all been working fine for years, but started going wrong
no-resolv
no-poll
server=8.8.8.8
server=4.4.4.4
server=192.168.7.1
domain=localdomain
dhcp-range=192.168.7.128,192.168.7.255,12h
dhcp-option=3,192.168.7.1
dhcp-option=19,0           # option ip-forwarding off
dhcp-option=44,192.168.7.101     # set netbios-over-TCP/IP nameserver(s) aka WINS server(s)
dhcp-option=45,192.168.7.101     # netbios datagram distribution server
dhcp-option=46,8           # netbios node type
dhcp-authoritative

An example smbtree output from after JACKIS-PC (ip address 192.168.7.248) was able to open \\watson\data but failed to open \\watson\music follows:

lp_load_ex: refreshing parameters
Initialising global parameters
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
params.c:pm_process() - Processing configuration file "/etc/samba/smb.conf"
Processing section "[global]"
added interface eth0 ip=192.168.7.101 bcast=192.168.7.255 netmask=255.255.255.0
Enter mark's password: 
tdb(/var/cache/samba/gencache.tdb): tdb_open_ex: could not open file /var/cache/samba/gencache.tdb: Permission denied
name_resolve_bcast: Attempting broadcast lookup for name WORKGROUP<0x1d>
Got a positive name query response from 192.168.7.101 ( 192.168.7.101 )
Connecting to 192.168.7.101 at port 445
Doing spnego session setup (blob length=74)
got OID=1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.10
got principal=not_defined_in_RFC4178@please_ignore
Got challenge flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x608a8215
NTLMSSP: Set final flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x60088215
NTLMSSP Sign/Seal - Initialising with flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x60088215
WORKGROUP
name_resolve_bcast: Attempting broadcast lookup for name WORKGROUP<0x1d>
Got a positive name query response from 192.168.7.101 ( 192.168.7.101 )
Connecting to 192.168.7.101 at port 445
Doing spnego session setup (blob length=74)
got OID=1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.10
got principal=not_defined_in_RFC4178@please_ignore
Got challenge flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x608a8215
NTLMSSP: Set final flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x60088215
NTLMSSP Sign/Seal - Initialising with flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x60088215
    \\WATSON                watson server (Samba, Ubuntu)
resolve_hosts: Attempting host lookup for name WATSON<0x20>
Connecting to 192.168.7.101 at port 445
Doing spnego session setup (blob length=74)
got OID=1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.10
got principal=not_defined_in_RFC4178@please_ignore
Got challenge flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x608a8215
NTLMSSP: Set final flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x60088215
NTLMSSP Sign/Seal - Initialising with flags:imilarly
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x60088215
        \\WATSON\IPC$               IPC Service (watson server (Samba, Ubuntu))
        \\WATSON\data               
        \\WATSON\music              
    \\LANGDALE-PIKE         
resolve_hosts: Attempting host lookup for name LANGDALE-PIKE<0x20>
Connecting to 192.168.7.233 at port 445
This has all been working fine for years, but started going wrong
Doing spnego session setup (blob length=320)
got OID=1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.30
got OID=1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.10
got principal=<null>
Got challenge flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x628a8215
NTLMSSP: Set final flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x60088215
NTLMSSP Sign/Seal - Initialising with flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x60088215
SPNEGO login failed: Logon failure
    \\JACKIS-PC             
resolve_hosts: Attempting host lookup for name JACKIS-PC<0x20>
Connecting to 192.168.7.248 at port 445
Doing spnego session setup (blob length=42)
got OID=1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.30
got OID=1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.10
got principal=<null>
Got challenge flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x628a8215
NTLMSSP: Set final flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x60088215
NTLMSSP Sign/Seal - Initialising with flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x60088215
SPNEGO login failed: Logon failure
```

Answer (score 1):

(Disclaimer - I'm a relative Linux newbie. I have more experience on Solaris)

This might be related to the problems I faced configuring Samba on Ubuntu 15.04 over the last few days. In my configuration, I was simply trying to set up shares on several Ubuntu desktops and a Windows 10 desktop, on a home network.

The symptoms I experienced were that Nautilus would be able to browse the network, but when I tried to authenticate, it would either fail and re-prompt for the password, or appear to succeed, but then cause Nautilus to crash or hang. On other occasions, it would connect, and I could successfully create files in the shared directories.

After reading a very large number of posts by others on similar subjects, I set debug level 10 on both the smbclient and the backend nmbd and smbd daemons and compared successful and unsuccessful connections.

The comparisons highlighted two problems which, once I'd fixed both of them, resolved my problems.

First, my host names were resolving to multiple IP addresses. This is because I have, in the past, connected the same machines to the router via WiFi and via ethernet. Because each interface has a different MAC address, the router has DHCP'ed different IP addresses to them, but used the same hostname.

This outcome can be observed if you use something like nslookup to resolve your hostname (here, home-file-svr only has a single address fortunately):

`$ nslookup home-file-svr
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53`

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   home-file-svr.home
Address: 192.168.1.68

I made the mistake of changing the hostnames the router used for these systems by adding -wifi and -wired suffixes in its home network setup (on the router), and then found that it wasn't resolving the names to local systems at all, and had bizarrely resolved to names on the Internet. So, in summary for this section, ensure that your hostname resolves to a single address.

Second, and much harder to debug, was why an smbclient connection would fail the first time, then work, then later fail again.

`$ smbclient //home-file-svr/public -U tim
Enter tim's password: 
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
 smbclient //home-file-svr/public -U tim
Enter tim's password: 
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 4.1.13-Ubuntu]
smb: >`

Furthermore, this only happened when there was more than one system up on the network. The culprit turned out to be winbind. Comparing the traces showed that the first connection attempt tries to create a cache entry for the GID to SID mapping with a large negative time (using the Unix zero time date - 1970). The second attempt didn't, and succeeds.

Removing winbind from all Ubuntu systems worked for my network as I don't have/haven't set up a Windows domain on my network.